# Как очистить и удалить блок на чистом javascript?

Tags: javascript

Я сделал форму отправки, но в ней есть две строки на jquery.
Не могу переделать, помогите.
Суть - очистить блок и вставить новые данные.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------

$(".bg-sp").empty();
$(".bg-sp").html(this.responseText);//исправить

//----------------------------------------------------------------

send.onclick = function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  Form = document.forms.data,
  formData = new FormData(Form)
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       $(".bg-sp").empty();
       $(".bg-sp").html(this.responseText);//исправить
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/backEnd/model/filter/index.php", true);
  xhttp.send(formData);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".bg-sp").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```